# How do I shut down Ubuntu after it blanks the screen?

Tags: 16.04, display, freeze

My Ubuntu 16.04 installation always becomes unresponsive after it blanks the screen (Standby is turned off.) I tried the power button and Enter; no luck. How can I shut it down without risk of damage to the system? Thanks.